# selected menu item

Tags: php, menus

The template I'm working on for a client has the following pages:

- Home : a custom static page that displays the content of a certain WP page, and the latest sticky posts. This is the front-page.php file.
- About us: a WP page
- Services : a WP page
- Events : a list of WP posts, in the Events category
- Blog : a list of WP in the Blog category

I'd like to highlight the current section in the main menu in CSS, but the only idea I have is to make a big list of PHP conditionals depending on the current case. For example if we are seeing the Events category, then we must be in the Events section, and so on.

Is there a more straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Pier, can you post some code? For example the main menu code your are using?

Comment: I'm using a typical ul li and links, but it really doesn't matter. The problem is the PHP logic to figure out what is the current page.

Comment: I asked because if you are using wordpress to create the menu, then wordpress adds classes that you can use. However, if you created the menu yourself then you do need if statements to figure out what page you're in.

Comment: Yes, I created the menu myself. Thanks, it seems my first idea is the only way to do it then.

Comment: @gdaniel considering the pages I've posted, is it possible to make the menu dynamic?

Comment: You can try using the wordpress menu option in the admin. It really depends how the backend is setup. Most pages would work fine, not sure about the Events page. Another way to do it, is to use jQuery to look at parts of the URL, Title of the page, or some other unique element to that page.. and apply the css accordingly. For instance if, if the page had an element with a unique ID, you could use jQuery to identify that page and automatically hide or show CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

I definetly suggest you to use WordPress menu feature, is quite easier to implement and you will never need to wory if the user want to rename or add new items.

Just add this to your functions.php:

```
    register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'main_menu' => 'Main menu',
    )
);
```

Then in header.php or wherever you have the menu add:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'menu_class' => 'the_main_menu' ) ); ?>
```

You can reuse your CSS classes also, please [check the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).